# Added captcha to form, now can't post form inputs to my processing script. How do?

Tags: php, forms, validation, captcha

I have a contact form 
(http://pastie.org/private/jkukpixcygibqkiipbu88w)

which used to post the input fields to a processing script in a separate php file that would then email them to me.

(http://pastie.org/private/iiakln02xfacvb58uuyyqq)

I've now added a Captcha (SweetCaptcha)

I've had to remove the "action="mailer.php" from the form so that the Captcha can validate on the same page, and it basically works like this.

If Captcha = successful > do this, else > do this.

My problem is, how can I put my mailing script inside the "Captcha = successful > do this" part? When i do it now, I get a ton of syntax errors/saying my functions aren't defined.

I hope I have explained this well enough

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Put an include between your `{ success }` ?

Comment: Hey, good idea. I tried this and I get the error

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /filepath/includes/head.php:32) in /file-path/contact-mailer.php on line 39

Comment: I wouldn't use it(sweetcaptcha) at all anymore: https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/06/sweetcaptcha-service-used-to-distribute-adware.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I luckily switched to Google's REcaptcha shortly after I posted this.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to get a code snippet, but you can either override the function you want in javascript or in the "do this" part you can change the action of the form and then "submit" it.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! I've added pasties with all of the relevant code! It's quite large amount for just a snippet.

How can I change the action of the form and submit it in the "do this" part?

Comment: There should be a server side and a client side to the captcha. When you submit the form with the captcha you should have some identifier that tells you that this form id and this captcha are the same. To submit with JavaScript is very easy, it is just to get the element of the form by name/id and then "submit()"